# SonataMediaBundle and S3 integration

Tags: symfony, amazon-s3, sonata-admin

I am trying to use SonataMediaBundle to upload images to S3. Is there any example I can refer to for this integration?

Here's what I did so far:

- create a bucket on S3
- update config.yml with sonata_media S3 attributes

sonata_media:

```
filesystem:

   s3:
        bucket: mybucket
        accessKey: myaccesskey
        secretKey: mysecretkey
        create: false
```

- add AWS SDK on autoloader.php

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue.
Turned out, I missed this line on my config file.

```
providers:
   image:
      filesystem: sonata.media.filesystem.local
```

Comment: Do you have a full example of your config file? (obviously without your actual real keys). I can't seem to get it to work. Nothing ever gets uploaded